# Forum redirects to home page on sending message, usernames not shown

Tags: php, html, json

I'm working on a forum with my friend.
When my friend tries to send a message in the forum, it redirects them to the mainpage. For some reason, this doesn't happen to me. However, for both of us the display names aren't shown.
Below is the php code for our forum

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Forums</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      if ($_COOKIE["username"] != "") {
        echo "<form action='index.php' method='post'>";
        echo "<textarea name='body'></textarea>";
        echo "<input name='mode' type='submit' value='send'></form>";
      }
     ?>
    <?php
      $forums = fopen("forums.json", "r");
      $forum = fread($forums, filesize("forums.json"));
      $forum = json_decode($forum);
      $messages = $forum->messages;
      fclose($forums);
      foreach ($messages as $message) {
        $author_data = "../user-data/{$message->author}.json";
        $author = fopen($author_data, "r");
        $author = fread($author, filesize($author_data));
        $author = json_decode($author);
        echo "<div class='message'>";
        echo "<div class='message-details'><img width=50 height=50 src='{$author->pfp}'><span class='username'>{$author->display_name}</span> <span class='date'>{$message->time[0]} {$message->time[1]}</span></div>";
        echo "<div class='message-body'>{$message->body}</div></div>";
      }
     ?>
     <?php
        if ($_POST["mode"] == "send") {
          $message->author = $_COOKIE["username"];
          $message->body = nl2br(str_replace(">","&gt",str_replace("<","&lt",$_POST["body"])));
          $message->time = array(date("Y-m-d") , date("H:i"));
          $message->id = strval(uniqid() * time());
          $forums = fopen("forums.json", "r");
          $forum = fread($forums, filesize("forums.json"));
          $forum = json_decode($forum);
          $messages = $forum->messages;
          array_unshift($messages, $message);
          $forum->messages = $messages;
          fclose($forums);
          $forumw = fopen("forums.json", "w");
          $newforum = json_encode($forum);
          fwrite($forumw, $newforum);
          fclose($forumw);
          header("Location: ../forums/");
          exit();
        }
      ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Json where the forum messages are shown

`{"messages":[{"author":"knitt","body":"sgsfg","time":["2021-03-14","11:25"],"id":"975883618420"},{"author":"knitt","body":"sfgsfgsgsf","time":["2021-03-14","11:25"],"id":"975883616608"}]}`

And the Json for a user

`{"password":"Encrypted password goes here","pfp":"\/images\/pfps\/index.png","display_name":"Knitt","desc":"I'm knitt."}`

Comment: Based on your code, header("Location: ../forums/"); redirects the user after a forum message is created, which is probably why your friend is getting redirected (as he or she should based on the code). As for the display name issue, have u checked the result of         $author = json_decode($author); ?

Comment: The URL "../forums/" is supposed to redirect the user to the same page, effectively reloading the page. I haven't checked the result of $author = json_decode($author); Will do.
Thanks for your help

Comment: If so then its likely that your relative path isn't working as you intend to. Try using an absolute path e.g https://example.com/forum/ instead and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you, I used "index.php" and it worked.